# What's this code? I need help solving

Tags: cipher

VTFOQ00ySXlOV3RhV0VsbllWZFpaMlZYT1RGSlIwNW9ZbWxDYTFwWFRuWmFSMVZuWkVkb2NHTjNQVDA9

Someone sent me this, and I can't solve it. I need help.

Comment: im very confused as to if this is an actual puzzle or a guy genuinely confused by what the code means

Comment: I was actually confused but now I am not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Original:

VTFOQ00ySXlOV3RhV0VsbllWZFpaMlZYT1RGSlIwNW9ZbWxDYTFwWFRuWmFSMVZuWkVkb2NHTjNQVDA9

Base64 (1):

> U1NCM2IyNWtaWElnYVdZZ2VXOTFJR05oYmlCa1pXTnZaR1VnZEdocGN3PT0=

Base64 (2):

> SSB3b25kZXIgaWYgeW91IGNhbiBkZWNvZGUgdGhpcw==

Base64 (3):

> I wonder if you can decode this

Comment: Could you please explain your answer more?

Comment: I don't think it's base64 though. I've tried translating from base64, did not work.

Comment: @NL628 The string is encoded with the [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding scheme. If you decode it three times, you get the solution.

Answer (score 2):

> This is Base64 encoded 'I wonder if you can decode this' 3 times.

Comment: Took me longer to write any of this than to figure it out (had to go back and replicate the number of iterations I think it ended up being four times) so that I could provide the how the answer was discovered.  SimpleMath though obviously posted long before I did.  Something about the "construct" though looked familiar, as unnatural as that is. :/